# Strange join results in GBQ

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running into query results in GBQ that I do not understand nor can I explain.

I am trying to join two tables that have exactly the same schema structure and may have duplicates.

My desire is to join the two tables taking all the rows from table1 and any additional rows in table2 that are not present in table1 based on a unique id.  This is a pretty common join scenario.

So, to test my join, I narrowed my where clause down so it points to a single row.  I verified that the row exist in each table and that the column data is identical in each.

Here is a the sample query I used to test that it returns a single row,

select t1.* from dataset1.homework t1 WHERE t1.book_id = 12345 AND t1.homework_id = 10337096 AND t1.homeworkresult_id = 12353139 AND t1.question_id = 2;

select t1.* from dataset2.homework t1 WHERE t1.book_id = 12345 AND t1.homework_id = 10337096 AND t1.homeworkresult_id = 12353139 AND t1.question_id = 2;

I verify that each returns a single row as I would expect.  Now if I join the two tables (in my case table1 will have the most rows).

Here is my join statement, that returns 30 ROWS, all duplicates.  I have NO idea where the additional rows are coming from or what bigquery is doing.  the EACH clause was required because my table sizes exceeded the minimum 8Mb compressed limit.

SELECT
t1.*
FROM dataset1.homework AS t1
LEFT JOIN EACH dataset2.homework AS t2
ON t1.homeworkresult_id = t2.homeworkresult_id
WHERE t1.book_id = 12345 AND t1.homework_id = 10337096 AND t1.homeworkresult_id = 12353139 AND t1.question_id = 2;

I would really appreciate if someone could shed some light on what the heck is going on here.

Thanks, J.D.

Comment: Do you have any repeated fields there? Please be aware the interface automatically flattens the data.

Comment: If Pentium10's answer doesn't help, I'd be happy to investigate further. You can send job IDs to jcondit@google.com.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  No repeated fields.  I solved it by using the "UNION" like GBQ Syntax SELECT * from (query1),(query2),...,(queryN)

Answer (score 2):

So I gave up on the JOIN and attacked the problem from a different angle.  I used a less documented feature of Google BigQuery that allows you to essentially union results from multiple queries. This works well if the schema structure across the tables being queried are identical.

The basic syntax is,

SELECT * from (query 1),(query 2), ...,(query N)

In my case, query 1 selected all rows from the first table that had the most rows, query 2 selected all the rows from the second table that were not in the first table.

J.D.